# Errors in insert at back for linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am making an attempt to build my library of elementary operations for linked list but I get into trouble with the function `push_back()` which works: Push the data at the end of the linked list.
Here is my source code:

```
node* push_back(node *dir, item datain)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = datain;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        dir = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        while (dir->next != NULL)
            dir = dir->next;
        dir->next = newnode;
    }
    return dir;
}
void printlist(node *dir)
{
    printf("%-50s%-50s%-20s\n", "Name", "Email", "Phone number");
    while (dir != NULL)
    {
        item temp = dir->data;
        printf("%-50s%-50s%-20s\n", temp.name, temp.email, temp.phone);
        dir = dir->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    node *dir = (node *) malloc(sizeof(dir));
    dir = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<3)
    {
        item temp = userdata();
        dir = push_back(dir, temp);
        i++;
    }
    printlist(dir);
    freelist(dir);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem: If I just insert 2 records (each record has name, email and phone number), then it's ok. However, If there are more than 2 records, as I print the whole records I have inserted, it just print out the two lastest record. I have checked my code on some websites but I find that they bare no resemblance as mine.
For example:

INPUT:

> Enter the name: Joey
>
> Enter the email: Joey@gmail.com
>
> Enter the phone number: 0235632514
>
> Enter the name: Mathew
>
> Enter the email: Mathew@gmail.com
>
> Enter the phone number: 012502252
>
> Enter the name: Waley
>
> Enter the email: Waley@gmail.com
>
> Enter the phone number: 036625125

OUTPUT:

> Name                             Email                                             Phone number
>
> Mathew                                            Mathew@gmail.com                                  012502252
>
> Waley                                             Waley@gmail.com                                   036625125

Comment: `node *dir = (node *) malloc(sizeof(dir));` looks wrong. If anything it should be `sizeof(*dir)`. Though you leak that memory right on the next line anyway, making this completely pointless

Comment: @UnholySheep It does not solve the problem I say. Actually my syntax is still right but it can be confusing

Comment: What I suspect is the problem is `dir = push_back(dir, temp);` - you "override" the pointer with the one returned by the function, which is always the second to last node of your list

Comment: @UnholySheep I agree with you but I find it hard to figure out the error here because it 's nearly the same as the code on the Internet

Comment: Comparing your code to code you find on the internet is a bad way to figure out problems. You need to step through your code using a debugger and/or analyze what you are doing on paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem :

> ```
>  node *dir = (node *) malloc(sizeof(dir));
>  dir = NULL;
> ```

so you have a memory leak because you loose the allocation, just do

```
node *dir = NULL;
```

Second problem *push_back* returns the last element of the list so doing

> ```
> dir = push_back(dir, temp);
> ```

*dir* now point to the last element and you lost the head of the list, so all elements except the last

One way is to modify *push_back* to return the (new) head of the list :

```
node* push_back(node * head, item datain)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    newnode->data = datain;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        return newnode;

    node * dir = head;

    while (dir->next != NULL)
       dir = dir->next;
    dir->next = newnode;

    return head;
}
```

but that supposes the caller always does something like *dir = push_back(dir, temp);*

an other way is to use double pointer :

```
void push_back(node ** head, item datain)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    newnode->data = datain;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = newnode;
    else {
      node * dir = *head;

      while (dir->next != NULL)
         dir = dir->next;
      dir->next = newnode;
    }
}
```

and the caller can just do *push_back(&dir, temp);* without taking the risk to forget to assign

Comment: As to the first problem, I still don't know why it is the error because ``dir = NULL`` here just informs that it is the empty list.
The second problem, I think your right, but I don't know how to return the head of the list. Can you show me the way to do it?

Comment: Thanks, I got the expected answer